# Can't read stdout output of external commands after deamonizing Python script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I wrote a RPC server `foo` in Python that I deamonized with

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --background \
                  --make-pidfile \
                  --pidfile /var/run/foo.pid \
                  -- /opt/foo
```

Everything works fine except that every use of `subprocess.check_call(some_cmd)` or `os.popen(some_cmd).read(1048576)` in my daemon returns an empty string compared to the case when I start `foo` in the foreground.

The external program `some_cmd` is still executed sucessfully (as I can see in the logs), yet I don't have access to the stuff it prints to stdout.

Why is that and what changes can I make to either the `start-stop-daemon` call or my Python code in ordert to fix this?

PS: I found that only the output of certain commands is now empty: `subprocess.check_output('echo "Hello World"', shell=True)` still behaves normally, whereas the output of `subprocess.check_output('/etc/init.d/apache2 --nocolor reload', shell=True)` is now empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself. The problem was that `start-stop-daemon` is setting the environment variable `EINFO_QUIET` when run with the `--quite` flag (not documented in the man pages...).

OpenRC init scripts then prints nothing to stdout when this variable is set. A simple

```
import os
os.environ["EINFO_QUIET"] = "NO"
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

From title of problem, if it is an attempt for stdout access,
it is possible if there is terminal with the process. When demonised, there is no terminal.